# Finding All The Values Of $(1+i)^{2i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

What I have tried

$$(1+i)^{2i}=e^{\log(1+i)^{2i}}=e^{2i(\log(1+i))}=e^{2i(\ln(\sqrt{2})+i(\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k))}=e^{2i\cdot \ln(\sqrt{2})}\cdot e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}-4\pi k}$$

Can we further simplify it?

Comment: $e^{2i\ln\sqrt2}=e^{i\ln2}=\cos(\ln2)+i\sin(\ln2)$.

Comment: In general, when we write $a^{b^c}$ we mean $a^{(b^c)}$. You mean $(a^b)^c$, and should put the parentheses around the expression to make it clear.

Comment: $$(1+i)^{2i}={{\rm e}^{-\pi/2}}\cos \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) +i{
{\rm e}^{-\pi/2}}\sin \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) 
$$

Comment: But in this case, we write $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$, rather than $(e^{\ln a})^b$, because $(x^y)^b$ is not necessarily equal to $x^{yb}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it is true just if $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews...you are right..i just saw that there is not an $i$ in the expression..i will delete my answer.

Comment: The only thing you can simplify is that $2\ln(\sqrt{2})=\ln 2$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Somehow I knew you were going to miss the point even before reading your (wrong) comment.

Comment: @Did. But this is coming from a CAS ! Can a CAS be wrong ? (jokes) ;Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed. :-)